# Parse eof or a character in nom

Tags: rust, nom

I'm parsing with the nom library.
I would like to match on something that is followed by an 'end', without consuming it.

A end for me is either `eof` or a char that satisfies a function `f: Fn(char) -> bool`.

I can use `f` with `nom::character::complete::satisfy`, `nom::bytes::take_while`, or many other `nom` functions.

The incompatabilites between `eof` and `f` makes it impossible for me to compose, with `nom` combinators or my own combinators.

This is illegal, because of opaque type:

```rust
fn end(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    match eof(i) {
        o @ Ok(_) => o,
        e @ Err(_) => peek(satisfy(f)),
    }
}
```

This is also illegal:

```rust
alt((eof, satisfy(f)))
```

I can't even make this work:

```rust
alt((eof, char(' ')))
```

I can't even make *THIS* work: (because match arms has incompatible types??)

```rust
fn end(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, ()> {
    match eof(i) {
        o @ Ok((sur, res)) => Ok((i, ())),
        e @ Err(_) => match satisfy(f) {
            Ok(_) => Ok((i, ())),
            e @ Err(_) => e,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by providing an error myself:

```rust
fn end(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, ()> {
    match eof::<&str, ()>(i) {
        o @ Ok((_, _)) => Ok((i, ())),
        e @ Err(_) => match satisfy::<_, _, ()>(is_url_terminative)(i) {
            Ok(_) => Ok((i, ())),
            Err(_) => Err(nom::Err::Error(Error {
                input: i,
                code: nom::error::ErrorKind::Permutation,
            })),
        },
    }
}
```